# Confirm full evacuation of vSAN host

Tags: vmware-esxi, vmware-vsan

Just placed my first host running VSAN 6.2 in to maintenance mode and selected full evacuation.  The task has completed and the host is in maintenance mode.  Part of me is worrying though about the "Full Evacuation" part of the VSAN migration.  Bar the initial selection I can see nothing in the or syslog to confirm that this is the option that was selected.

Does anyone know a way to confirm that all the data has been migrated?  My thinking is that if this was a full migration for a host rebuild if someone had selected the wrong option ("Easily Accessible" for example) then data could be lost in an FTT=1 cluster.

Comment: Is the server in maintenance mode? if so it's fully evacuated

Comment: indeed it is.  But if an "Easily Accessible" option had been ticked then would it not also still enter "Maintenance Mode"?  The vsphere docs seem to suggest this.

Answer (score 2):

In **vSphere client** you can watch amount of data that was migrated from first HOST to second one.

As far as i see from https://blogs.vmware.com/virtualblocks/2016/02/18/choosing-the-correct-vsan-maintenance-mode-option/ there are no special success notification.